# Go templating in xml file

Tags: xml, go, kubernetes-helm

I'm taking an input via values.yaml in a helm package and trying to use the value in an xml file. But it is failing. Please point out what it is that i'm doing wrong.
Values.yaml contains:

```
ere:
  AdmServerPort: "9090"
```

In the file I've used it as:

```
<Argument Name="Port" Value="{{ .Values.ere.AdmServerPort | default "9090" }}"/>
```

I'm using configmap to put this inside my pod after editing dynamically. Please Help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I didn't paste the error as it contains whole xml. I tried helm upgrade and it failed with render error. Also i tried changing the lines which i modified (which are only these mentioned lines) as it was working before for sure. But it didn't help.

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: render error in "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml": template: eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml:25:28: executing "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml" at <include (print $.Tem...>: error calling include: template: eric-em-ere/templates/configmap.yaml:14:22: executing                                                   "eric-em-ere/templates/configmap.yaml" at <tpl (.Files.Get "fil...>: error calling tpl: Error during tpl function execution for "<PoolServer>...
```

whole error goes on with xml template and ends with:

```
: parse error in "eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml": template: eric-em-ere/templates/deployment-ere.yaml:36: bad character U+002D '-'
```

Comment: You forgot to mention *how* it is "failing". What error are you getting? What output do you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the exact problem with your attempt?